# kendo ui JSP dropdownlist with server side binding

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am using the Kendo UI JSP Wrapper controls and I am trying to use the Kendo Dropdownlist with the server binding.

I am using Struts2 for the Controller actions.

```
**Here is my code for Action class**
public String execute() throws Exception {
        editMode = false;
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest(); 
        DiseaseTrackingDelegate dtd = new DiseaseTrackingDelegate();
        //Below call will get list of all objects
        List<DstLookupType> allDstLookupTypes = dtd.getDstLookupTypes(dstLookupType, user.getCurrentClientId());
        //Below call will get specific list of objects from the above list
        List<DstLookupType> specificDstLookupTypes = getSpecificDstLookupTypes(Constants.DST_LOOKUP_GRP_TYPE_1, allDstLookupTypes);
        //this.primaryDiagnosisTypes = dstLookupTypes;
        //I am setting the specific list to the request.setAttribute. Can I use the below code?
        request.setAttribute("primaryDiagList", specificDstLookupTypes);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

public List<DstLookupType> getSpecificDstLookupTypes(int grpLookupTypeId, List<DstLookupType> allDstLookupTypes)
{
    List<DstLookupType> lookupTypes = new ArrayList<DstLookupType>();
    allDstLookupTypes.forEach(dstLTypes->{
        if( Integer.parseInt(dstLTypes.getFDstLookupGrpTypeId()) == grpLookupTypeId){

            lookupTypes.add(dstLTypes);
        }
    });
    return lookupTypes;
}        

***Below is the code in JSP***

<kendo:dropdownlist name="primarydiagnosis" dataTextField="lookupValue" dataValueField="dstLookupTypeId">
        <kendo:dataSource data="${primaryDiagList}"></kendo:dataSource>
</kendo:dropdownlist>
```

I am using the http request attribute that was set in the action class as the kendo:datasource data element. but its not working.

I even set it to a form element which I commented in the above action code, but that is also not working.

How do I use the Kendo dropdownlist with Server bind using the Struts 2 and JSP.

Thanks

Comment: You should clarify what is not working to be more clear, as far as it's written everything looks fine.

Comment: I set the DSTLOOKUPTYPE objects list in the request attribute in the action and I am trying to use the same attribute in the kendo:dataSource data element in the JSP. But the dropdown values are not populated and the kendo dropdown list control is also not displayed.